# JAXB @XmlIDREF in XmlAdapter for immutable objects

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using `XmlAdapter` for immutable objects as proposed in this blog post: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html. This works fine, but not with references to other immutable objects in my adapters. Is there any way to handle this with JAXB?

Below there is an example which does not work if the person's xml tag comes after the company's xml tag which references the person.

**Immutable objects:**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PersonAdapter.class)
public class Person {
  private final String id;
  private final String name;

  public Person(String id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CompanyAdapter.class)
public class Company {
  private final String name;
  private final Person principal;

  public Company(String name, Person principal) {
    this.name = name;
    this.principal = principal;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public Person getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }
}
```

**PersonAdapter:**

```
public class PersonAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedPerson, Person> {
  public static class AdaptedPerson {
    @XmlID
    @XmlAttribute
    String id;
    @XmlAttribute
    String name;
  }

  @Override
  public AdaptedPerson marshal(Person v) throws Exception {
    AdaptedPerson a = new AdaptedPerson();
    a.id = v.getId();
    a.name = v.getName();
    return a;
  }

  @Override
  public Person unmarshal(AdaptedPerson v) throws Exception {
    return new Person(v.id, v.name);
  }
}
```

**CompanyAdapter:**

```
public class CompanyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedCompany, Company> {
  public static class AdaptedCompany {
    @XmlAttribute
    String name;
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlAttribute
    Person principal;
  }

  @Override
  public AdaptedCompany marshal(Company v) throws Exception {
    AdaptedCompany a = new AdaptedCompany();
    a.name = v.getName();
    a.principal = v.getPrincipal();
    return a;
  }

  @Override
  public Company unmarshal(AdaptedCompany v) throws Exception {
    return new Company(v.name, v.principal);
  }
}
```